# Weird result sets counts upon datetime criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table (the server is SQL Server 2016)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
    [RefID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [LG_ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [APP_SERVER_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [WEB_SERVER_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [WEB_BROWSER_ID] [int] NULL,
    [CLIENT_TYPE_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OS_NAME_ID] [int] NULL,
    [CLIENT_VERSION] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [OS_VERSION] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [BROWSER_VERSION] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [DETAILS] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [LG_SOURCE_TABLE] [char](2) NOT NULL,
    [LG_TIME] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RefID] ASC,
    [LG_ID] ASC,
    [LG_SOURCE_TABLE] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [Primary]
) ON [Primary]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_MyTable_LG_TIME] ON [dbo].[MyTable]
(
    [LG_TIME] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RefID] ASC,
    [LG_ID] ASC,
    [LG_SOURCE_TABLE] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

And I am querying data with the following methods (I am using only method 1, the other are tests that I am doing):

```
METHOD 1:
SELECT
    [RefID],
    [LG_ID],
    [APP_SERVER_ID],
    [WEB_SERVER_ID],
    [WEB_BROWSER_ID],
    [CLIENT_TYPE_ID],
    [OS_NAME_ID],
    [CLIENT_VERSION],
    [OS_VERSION],
    [BROWSER_VERSION],
    [DETAILS],
    [LG_SOURCE_TABLE],
    [LG_TIME]
FROM
    [MyTable] WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE
    [LG_TIME] >= '20190923'
    AND [LG_TIME] < '20190924'
--returns 19.880.317 rows

METHOD 2:
SELECT
    [RefID],
    [LG_ID],
    [APP_SERVER_ID],
    [WEB_SERVER_ID],
    [WEB_BROWSER_ID],
    [CLIENT_TYPE_ID],
    [OS_NAME_ID],
    [CLIENT_VERSION],
    [OS_VERSION],
    [BROWSER_VERSION],
    [DETAILS],
    [LG_SOURCE_TABLE],
    [LG_TIME]
FROM
    [MyTable] WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE
    CAST([LG_TIME] AS DATE) = '20190923'
--returns 19.879.488 rows

METHOD 3:
SELECT
    *
FROM
    [MyTable] WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE
    [LG_TIME] >= '20190923'
    AND [LG_TIME] < '20190924'
--returns 19.880.186 rows

METHOD 4:
SELECT
    *
FROM
    [MyTable] WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE
    CAST([LG_TIME] AS DATE) = '20190923'
--returns 19.879.488 rows
```

And as you can see I am having different result sets each time.
I don't understand why this is happening, am I doing something wrong?
Which is the correct/safe way to get the data I need based on datetime range?

I am doing a bcp out/in from production server (which has 1.2 billion rows but will be truncated soon) to an archive (which has 10.5 billion rows) and sometimes I am losing a record because they have the same [LG_TIME] (maybe I will create a different question about that).

EDIT 1: Some extra info:

- The query (METHOD 1) is part of BCP OUT routine that happens daily at about 00:05 and the date range is always the same, 2 current days ago.
- I have strict guidelines to always use WITH (NOLOCK) at queries at production servers.
- There are millions of rows that have LG_TIME = NULL at the table but these rows are obsolete and will be deleted, i don't know if these rows cause any issues with my query.
- The table is part of logging mechanism of the application, only INSERTS are happening and DELETEs very early morning (about 02:00-03:00) when the daily archiving is success. No one else is reading the table that time.

EDIT 2 (2019-09-26 10:30):
So i added `LG_TIME IS NOT NULL` to all my queries at where criteria and these are my results:

METHOD 1: 19.879.488 rows
METHOD 2: 19.879.488 rows
METHOD 3: 19.880.036 rows
METHOD 4: 19.879.488 rows

Still weird!

Comment: I don't know the reasons for that to happen, but in my workplace there's a convention to convert datetime ALWAYS using `convert(datetime, COL, 103)`

Comment: Does your table have a PK? Can do you the second select `EXCEPT` the first one and check the dates on the records the pop up? Also make sure that there is no process operating on that set in between the queries.

Comment: @EzLo the table has a PK (i have it at my first code segment), also i am reading data that are 2 days old and no-one is reading at that daterange when we doing the transfer (or at least i hope so, i don't have access to that kind of information).

Comment: Why are you using `WITH (NOLOCK)`? Be consistent on using `Cast` to convert the date as @HagaiWild suggests. Also, are any of the `LG_TIME` NULL? This could give you undetermined results as well. Have you taken the datasets from all the results and figured out what rows are different?

Comment: @WEI_DBA i am reading from production table and our guidelines are to always use WITH (NOLOCK).There are many LG_TIME=NULL rows but they are very old compared to the ones i am trying to export, (we will clean out this table from irrelevant data). Unfortunately it is not very easy to compare datasets from the production environment due to process & memory restrictions.

Comment: Are you sure the rows with the LG_TIME in that range were not changing between queries. i.e. inserts or deletes. I have been caught out by that in the past.

Comment: LG_TIME IS nullable in the table definition. Do you have null value at all? Can you try to add LG_TIME IS NOT NULL to the where conditions to all the queries.

Comment: @PeterHe there are records with LG_TIME=NULL but they are very old comparing the date range i am querying. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: There is no difference between 1 and 3 and yet your record count is different. Something funky is up here. Are there deletes happening on this table. I can't imagine any other reason why a record count would change between two identical queries.

Comment: @Andrew the rows are not changing because there are only insertions and no updates at the table.

Comment: Remove nolock and run your queries again.

Comment: I'm guessing null values.  Try convert(date,isnull(LG_TIME,'1900-01-01))

Comment: As already mentioned, two of the queries are the same yet you get different results. So no matter how much you say the rows aren't changing... they probably are. You need to find some sample rows and inspect them and see the difference. I suggest you `ORDER BY LG_TIME` and check records atthe edges. It also doesn't help that you have a `DATETIME` (has a time component) yet you are searching on date literals.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid well if they are changing then we sure have visitors from the past =p  I am using the literal "YYYYMMDD" for date range, isn't the same as "YYYYMMDD hh:mi:ss:mmm" as i believe that the time is being translated as 00:00:00.000? I think that the nulls have something to do with this weird issue but unfortunately i wont be 100% until we delete them from the production table.